# CakePHP 2.x: Join on belongsto

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join, belongs-to

in my model 'mesn' i have belongsto relations:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Order' => array(
            'className' => 'Order', 'foreignKey' => 'order_id', 'conditions' => '', 'fields' => '', 'order' => ''
        ), 'SaleOrder' => array(
            'className' => 'SaleOrder', 'foreignKey' => 'sale_order_id', 'conditions' => '', 'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ), 'ShippedBox' => array(
            'className' => 'Box', 'foreignKey' => 'shipped_box_id', 'conditions' => '', 'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    ); /*     * * hasMany associations** @var array
```

In one of my model-functions i want to join another table on the "belongsto" "ShippedBox" (table: boxes). But doesn't matter how i try to write the join i get an error message of unknown column:

```
$arr_s_result = $this->find('all', array(
  'joins' => array(
    array('table' => 'shipments',
      'alias' => 'MyShipments',
      'type' => 'INNER',
      'conditions' => array(
      'MyShipments.id = ShippedBox.shipment_id'
    )
  )),
  'conditions' => array('Mesn.name' => $arr_search), 'recursive' => 0
));
```

I have tried:

```
'MyShipments.id = ShippedBox.shipment_id'
```

and

```
'MyShipments.id = box.shipment_id'
```

and even

```
'MyShipments.id = Boxes.shipment_id'
```

where the table "boxes" with the field "shipment_id" exists.

How can i get this join working?

Answer (score 0):

```
'MyShipments.id = box.shipment_id'
```

to:

```
'MyShipments.id = Box.shipment_id'
```

Also what about this:

```
$arr_s_result = $this->find('all', array(
                              'conditions' => array('Mesn.name' => $arr_search), 'recursive' => 0
```

));

The belongsTo join is done automatically.

Comment: maybe you don't need to do the join? As belongsTo is done automatically?

Comment: the problem i see from the sql statement that's executed is that it adds the join at the beginning of all JOINS where boxes is not "known" yet.

Comment: that was the original query, but it didn't resolved the depedencies on  boxes to shipments

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do something like use subqueries to get what you want -

```
$arr_s_result = $this->find('all', array(
     'joins' => array(
          array('table' => '(SELECT boxes.id, [enter other fields you need here] FROM shipments JOIN boxes ON boxes.shipment_id = shipments .id)',
          'alias' => 'MyShipments',
          'type' => 'INNER',
          'conditions' => array(
        'Mens.shipped_box_id = MyShipments.id'
       )
    )),
  'conditions' => array('Mesn.name' => $arr_search), 'recursive' => 0
));
```

Comment: looks like a good solution. will test when back to work tomorrow and give further comment or accept